# Problem with panning and zooming in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, javascript

I'm interested in detecting when a user moves or pans a map so that I can run a new query on a database based on their location. However, the following code causes the panning and zooming controls to go crazy:

```
map.events.register("moveend", map, function(){              
    getValues(map.center);               
    });
```

If I comment out these lines, there appears to be no problem. If they are included, after two pans or zooms, the map suddenly jumps to half-way around the world (it looks similar to 0 lat, 0 long). I'm unsure what I am doing incorrectly.

The other problem I have regarding the pan/zooming is that the `movend` does not really seem to wait until the user has finished moving or panning. Queries seem to be fired off even as the map is being moved and panned. Again, I'm not sure if this is a problem with how I am detecting this but it does not seem to behave as I thought it would.

EDIT: Including `getValues` function also:

```
getValues = function(c){

    c.transform(map.getProjectionObject(), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326") )
    console.log(c.lat, c.lon)

    $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/query.php" ,  
            data:{x: c.lat, y:c.lon},  
            async: true,
            success: function(r){
                    console.log(r);
            }, 
        dataType:'json'
        }); 

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your problem.  Try map.getCenter().  You are transforming the map center point which is likely the cause of your problem.

Comment: Yes, that does fix the 'thrashing'. However, on the third zoom/pan it throws the map to some random place in the world which stops when I comment out the `map.events....` piece as far as I can tell.

Comment: Update the source in the question so I can see that you've replace map.center with map.getCenter().

Answer (score 5):

I've used this event successfully.  A delay method similar to the one [here](http://pastebin.com/s1zdME79) can help any thrashing.  The actual method looks like this:

```
delay: function( timeout, id, callback )
    {
            this.delays = this.delays || [];
            var delay = this.delays[ id ];
            if ( delay )
            {
                    clearTimeout ( delay );
            }
            delay = setTimeout ( callback, timeout );
            this.delays[ id ] = delay;
    }
```

Usage Example:

```
delay(1000, "uniqueId", function() {
    getValues(map.getCenter()); 
});
```

I suspect your getValues method is modifying the map causing the moveend event to fire.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ca0v. Do you place your example delay within the `map.events.register("moveend", map, function(){ ... })` function? I would be surprised if my `getValues` method moves the map.

Comment: yes - register("moveend", map, function() { $.delay(...) }) where "$" is a reference to the object containing the delay function.  This is necessary because of the this.delays references.